# How to resolve ucrtbase.dll APPCRASH with python (ucrtbase.DLL)

Tags: python, crash

I made exe file by python.
I'm using the following command:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --onfile gui.py
```

but when I excute `gui.exe`, it crashes:

```
Problem signing:

Problem Event Name: APPCRASH

Application name: gui.Exe

Application version: 0.0.0.0

Application timestamp: 5a2e9fe6

Error Module Name: **ucrtbase.DLL**

Error Module Version: 10.0.10586.78

Error Module Timestamp: 5879aa7b

Exception Code: 40000015

Exception Offset: 0008469a

OS version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4

Locale ID: 1042

Additional Information 1: f997

Tip 2: f997d3aa488aa2577b4933f22e55cb2d

Tip 3: 6403

Tip 4: 640395134c67d4ec87d3c630dcc2b585
```

**Why does this happen? How can I resolve this problem?**

Comment: What does those Korean words mean in English? Is it relevant?

Comment: @KaiserKatze edited korean to english

Comment: Did you mean `--onefile` instead of `--onfile`?

Answer (score 0):

I found it answer. is right??

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3615

Python 3.7 is not yet supported. Also see the manual https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/usage.html?#windows

Comment: You should test your idea with Python 2.7 then.